Manage Trusted Extensions in VSCODE has options greyed out, and I need to turn them off
I have two GitHub accounts signed in to my VSCode, where one has a Copilot license. However, I can't use Copilot because it's using my GitHub account without a Copilot license.
Following this answer, I gathered I was to turn off the trusted extension selection for that GitHub account, and leave it enabled on the account with the license.
However, my extensions are greyed out for some reason, leaving me unable to untick them off my account. Trusted Extensions greyed out
I tried signing out of the account without the license, but that didn't change anything for some reason. VSCode continues to refuse to use the GitHub account with the license.
